# Google Sheets API verification flow does not provide a verification code

Tags: google-sheets-api

According to [this article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php), I should enable the Google Sheets API (done), copy and paste a blob of code into file quickstart.php and in terminal on the server run

```
$ php quickstart.php
```

This then prompts:

```
$ php quickstart.php 
Open the following link in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=<something>.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.website.com%2F&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets.readonly&prompt=select_account%20consent
Enter verification code:
```

So I open the link in my browser, accept that my.website.com gains access to my sheets, and then I'm redirected to the frontpage of my.website.com.

So what do I enter as verification code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, please check the URL of the redirected page on the browser. When you see the URL, in your situation, I think that you can see the following URL.

```
http://my.website.com/?code=#####&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

In this case, the code is `#####` of `code=#####` which is the query parameter. Please copy the code and put to `Enter verification code:` of the terminal you run `$ php quickstart.php`. By this, `token.json` of `$tokenPath = 'token.json';` including the access token and refresh token is created. After this, when you run `$ php quickstart.php`, the script uses the access token retrieved by the refresh token. By this, the authorization process is not required. About the expiration of the refresh token, please check [the official document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration).

#### Reference:

- [Refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

Comment: Ah, it was in the URL! Among a lot of other parameters. Who'd have guessed. You'd *think* they'd care to mention that in the guide. Oh well. Thank you very, very much! :-)

Comment: @OZ1SEJ Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.